# Can't turn WiFi off from lockscreen status bar options - Action Not Allowed [Nougat]

Tags: wi-fi, lock-screens, 7.0-nougat

Recently updated my moto g4+ to nougat and now I'm not able to toggle WiFi and some other actions from lockscreen status bar.

Are you guys having the same issue? How to fix it?
follow the attached screenshots if you couldn't understand my issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's possibly us. Give us some time to diagnose.

Comment: Well, the error message says it's disabled by some organizational policy. So is your phone linked to a work account of some kind?

Comment: no.. it's my personal phone